# Anylogic error "trying to start statechart twice"

Tags: anylogic

I have a population called "cannonballPorts" of agent type "Cannonball"
Why does it gives me this error?
"trying to start statechart twice"
I just called "inject()" into a source that generate agents of type "Cannonball" in the previous population.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We will need more information, show screenshots and code as applicable. To learn more about asking good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And also read here for AnyLogic questions on SOF: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow :)